# Divide by Zero in Mean()?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to write some code to compute mean, Variance, Standard Deviation, FWHM, and finally evaluate the Gaussian Integral. I've been running into a division by zero error that I can't get past and I would like to know the solution for this ?

Where it's throwing an error I've tried to throw an exception handler as follows

```
Average = (sum(yvalues)) / (len(yvalues)) try: return (sum(yvalues) / len(yvalues))
expect ZeroDivisionError:
  return 0
```

```
xvalues = []
yvalues = []

def generate():
    for i in range(0,300):
        a = rand.uniform((float("-inf") , float("inf")))
        b = rand.uniform((float("-inf") , float("inf")))
        xvalues.append(i)

        ### Defining the variable 'y'  
        y = a * (b + i)

        yvalues.append(y) + 1



def mean():
    Average = (sum(yvalues))/(len(yvalues))
    print("The average is", Average)
    return Average
def varience():
    # This calculates the SD and the varience
    s =  []  
    for i in yvalues:
        z = i - mean()
        z = (np.abs(i-z))**2
        s.append(y)**2
    t = mean()
    v = numpy.sqrt(t)
    print("Answer for Varience is:", v)
    return v
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Tuesday.py", line 42, in <module>
    def make_gauss(sigma=varience(), mu=mean(), x = random.uniform((float("inf"))*-1, float("inf"))):
  File "Tuesday.py", line 35, in varience
    t = mean()
  File "Tuesday.py", line 25, in mean
    Average = (sum(yvalues))/(len(yvalues))
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that are not quite right as people noted above.

```
import random
import numpy as np

def generate():
    xvalues, yvalues = [], []

    for i in range(0,300):
        a = random.uniform(-1000, 1000)
        b = random.uniform(-1000, 1000)
        xvalues.append(i)

        ### Defining the variable 'y'  
        y = a * (b + i)

        yvalues.append(y)

    return xvalues, yvalues

def mean(yvalues):
    return sum(yvalues)/len(yvalues)

def variance(yvalues):
    # This calculates the SD and the varience
    s =  []

    yvalues_mean = mean(yvalues)

    for y in yvalues:
        z = (y - yvalues_mean)**2
        s.append(z)
    t = mean(s)
    return t

def variance2(yvalues):
    yvalues_mean = mean(yvalues)
    return sum( (y-yvalues_mean)**2 for y in yvalues) / len(yvalues)

# Generate the xvalues and yvalues
xvalues, yvalues = generate()

# Now do the calculation, based on the passed parameters
mean_yvalues = mean(yvalues)
variance_yvalues = variance(yvalues)
variance_yvalues2 = variance2(yvalues)

print('Mean {}  variance {} {}'.format(mean_yvalues, variance_yvalues, variance_yvalues2))

# Using Numpy

np_mean = np.mean(yvalues)
np_var = np.var(yvalues)

print('Numpy: Mean {}  variance {}'.format(np_mean, np_var))
```

The way variance was calculated isn't quite right, but given the comment of  "SD and variance" you were probably going to calculate both.

The code above gives 2 (well, 3) ways to do what I understand you were trying to do but I changed a few of the methods to clean them up a bit.  `generate()` returns two lists now.  `mean()` returns the mean, etc.  The function `variance2()` gives an alternative way to calculate the variance but using a list comprehension style.

The last couple of lines are an example using `numpy` which has all of it built in and, if available, is a great way to go.

The one part that wasn't clear was the `random.uniform(float("-inf"), float("inf")))` which seems to be an error (?).

Comment: Thanks for the insight I understand now what went wrong with the varience calculation sorry about the rough code this is my first time using Python for more Mathmatical things

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `mean` before you call `generate`.

This is obvious since `yvalues.append(y) + 1` (in `generate`) would have caused another error (`TypeError`) since `.append` returns `None` and you can't add 1 to `None`.

Change `yvalues.append(y) + 1` to `yvalues.append(y + 1)` and then make sure to call `generate` before you call `mean`.

Also notice that you have the same error in `varience` (which should be called `variance`, btw). `s.append(y)**2` should be `s.append(y ** 2)`.

Another error you have is that the stacktrace shows `make_gauss(sigma=varience(), mu=mean(), x = random.uniform((float("inf"))*-1, float("inf")))`.

I'm pretty sure you don't actually want to call `varience` and `mean` on this line, just reference them. So also change that line to `make_gauss(sigma=varience, mu=mean, x = random.uniform((float("inf"))*-1, float("inf")))`